# PhpStorm Laravel Homestead "Error: Test class is not specified or invalid"

Tags: laravel, phpunit, homestead

I try to debug a single Laravel 5.5 test method in PhpStorm in Homestead and get the following error from PhpStorm

```
Error: Test class is not specified or invalid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved this issue by entering the "Path to composer.json" in the PhpStorm settings under "PHP -> Composer" and enabling the setting "Synchronize IDE Settings with composer.json"